# Artemis 2.18.0 replica set doesn't work properly

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have running Artemis version 2.17.0 replica set with master and two slaves. It works fine when I check "Broker diagram" view in the web console I see connection between master and slave (the other slave as a backup) as on the picture

[image: Master and Slave Artemis 2.17.0]

I upgraded now Artemis to 2.18.0 version and after restarting all artemis brokers when I check "Broker diagram" I see only master node and there is no link to the slave like on the picture above. The other two nodes are running as a slaves so there is only one master.

As I said on Artemis-2.17.0 it works.

Someone knows why is that ? here is for example the `broker.xml` for master node

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>

<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>0.0.0.0</name>


      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>

      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>

      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>

      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>

      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>

      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>

      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>

      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>

      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      
      <journal-buffer-timeout>28000</journal-buffer-timeout>

      <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>

      <!-- how often we are looking for how many bytes are being used on the disk in ms -->
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>

      <!-- once the disk hits this limit the system will block, or close the connection in certain protocols
           that won't support flow control. -->
      <max-disk-usage>100</max-disk-usage>

      <!-- should the broker detect dead locks and other issues -->
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>

      <critical-analyzer-timeout>150000</critical-analyzer-timeout>

      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>

      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
      
      <page-sync-timeout>1628000</page-sync-timeout>

        <global-max-size>204Mb</global-max-size>
      <!-- Connectors -->
      <connectors>
         <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://artemis01:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/client_ts.p12;trustStorePassword=12345</connector>
      </connectors>
      
      <acceptors>
        <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://artemis01:61616?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/broker_ks.p12;keyStorePassword=123456</acceptor>
      </acceptors>

      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
            <retry-interval-multiplier>3</retry-interval-multiplier>
            <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
            <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
            <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
      
    <broadcast-groups>
       <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
        <local-bind-address>artemis01</local-bind-address>
        <local-bind-port>9876</local-bind-port>
        <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
        <group-port>9876</group-port>
        <broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
        <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
       </broadcast-group>
    </broadcast-groups> 

    <discovery-groups>
       <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
        <local-bind-address>artemis01</local-bind-address>
         <local-bind-port>9876</local-bind-port>
          <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
          <group-port>9876</group-port>
          <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
       </discovery-group>
    </discovery-groups>
    
    <network-check-list>artemis02,artemis03</network-check-list>    
    <network-check-period>5000</network-check-period>
    <network-check-timeout>2000</network-check-timeout>
    <network-check-ping-command>ping -c 1 -t %d %s</network-check-ping-command>
    <network-check-ping6-command>ping6 -c 1 %2$s</network-check-ping6-command>
      
      <!-- Other config -->
      <ha-policy>
        <replication>
          <master>
            <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
          </master>
        </replication>
      </ha-policy>

      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="exampleQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="exampleQueue"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="DLQ">
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <auto-create-dead-letter-resources>true</auto-create-dead-letter-resources>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <address-setting match="exampleQueue">            
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>                      
            <redelivery-delay>1000</redelivery-delay>    
            <max-delivery-attempts>3</max-delivery-attempts>
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <page-size-bytes>1048576</page-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <!-- Uncomment the following if you want to use the Standard LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin pluging to log in events
      <broker-plugins>
         <broker-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin">
            <property key="LOG_ALL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONNECTION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SESSION_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_CONSUMER_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_DELIVERING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_SENDING_EVENTS" value="true"/>
            <property key="LOG_INTERNAL_EVENTS" value="true"/>
         </broker-plugin>
      </broker-plugins>
      -->

        <diverts>
        </diverts>

   </core>
</configuration>
```

Log from Master - artemis01

```xml
 AMQ222208: SSL handshake failed for client from /195.10.125.225:58790: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown.
```

Logs from Slave - artemis02

```xml
2021-08-24 00:07:06,544 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ214016: Failed to create netty connection: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No name matching artemis01.mydomain.com found
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:325) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:268) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1340) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.onConsumeCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1215) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:1158) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:445) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1260) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1247) [java.base:]
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1192) [java.base:]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.runDelegatedTasks(SslHandler.java:1550) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1396) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1237) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1286) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-all-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching artemis01.mydomain.com found
        at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:229) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:102) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:452) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:412) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:292) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144) [java.base:]
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:1318) [java.base:]
```

Comment: Is this just a problem with the web console? Do the master and slave actually pair up successfully and start replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a simple pair of brokers using replication and the "Broker Diagram" displays both the master and the slave as expected:
[image: Broker Diagram]
Ensure you have the "Show Backup Brokers" checkbox selected.

Regarding the SSL issue, see the [upgrade instructions for 2.18.0](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/versions.html#2180) in the documentation:

> ...core clients will now expect the `CN` or Subject Alternative Name values of the broker's SSL certificate to match the hostname in the client's URL.
>
> ...
>
> To deal with this you can do one of the following:
>
> - Update your SSL certificates to use a hostname which matches the hostname in the client's URL. This is the recommended option with regard to security.
> - Update any connector using `sslEnabled=true` to also use `verifyHost=false`. Using this option means that you won't get the extra security of hostname verification, but no certificates will need to change. This essentially restores the previous default behavior.

Comment: I double checked the "show backup brokers" checkbox was selected. May be some ping timeouts should I reduce/increase ? I found also really confusing  artemis documentation. I created for test purpose "test-broker" of artemis-2.18.0 and I realized that default values what are recommended in documentation of artemis are not corresponding to the values which I see in ```/test-broker/etc/broker.xml```. So what default values should I use then ?

Comment: I don't know what ping timeouts would be relevant here. I asked this previously, but you didn't answer - do the master and slave actually pair up successfully and start replication? Can you share the logs from both the live and the backup?

Comment: Also, what default values are you referring to and what might they have to do with this issue?

Comment: I haven't checked yet if replication starts and works. how will I prove that master and slave pair up successfully ? I assume not if there is no broker connection in the web console

Comment: There should be clear indications in the log that two brokers have paired and are replicating. Please share your logs for inspection as previously requested.

Comment: not yet, I updated back to 2.17.0 will try it later again with 2.18.0 on the live environment because only there I get this issue

Comment: I updated my post with logs from artemis-2.18.0. The error with SSL looks weird because I'm using the same setup for certificates and its running fine on artemis-2.17.0 I just upgraded artemis version and got this error. Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Justin did you see my updated post ? any ideas?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Does it mean that dirty fix would be add verifyHost=false to the URL in broker.xml for <connector> and <acceptor> ? Or should I add this also everywhere where I use broker URL in Java clients ?

Comment: That depends on if you're using 1-way or 2-way SSL. If you're using 1-ways SSL you just need to update your `connector` elements. If you're using 2-way SSL then you'll need to update both the `connector` and `acceptor`.

Comment: ok, and what about the second part of the question, should I also add this property to the connection URL for all clients where will be established connection with Artemis ?

Comment: Yes, of course you should add this property to the connection URL for all clients. That's covered in the documentation I linked. Although it might be simpler to just update the broker's SSL certificate and enforce industry-standard security practices.

Comment: I don't really get part with matching hostname for SSL certificates. I'm using Self-Signed certificate. I have private.key ```Issuer: C=DE, ST=Bayern, L=Munich, O=PC24, OU=IT, CN=procheck24/emailAddress=procheck-it@procheck24.de
 Issuer: C=US, ST=Maryland, L=Aberdeen, O=TestCompany, OU=IT, CN=test/emailAddress=test@gmail.de``` and then I'm generating trustStore and keyStore for clients and broker's. In this case hostname should match right ?

Comment: Perhaps you should open a new question about updating your SSL certificate. The comments here aren't a great place to deal with this.

Comment: ok, I will do later then. Thanks for your help!