# Updating SSL certificates for ActiveMQ Artemis 2.18.0

Tags: ssl, activemq-artemis

I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0 replication with self-signed certificates. After trying to update to 2.18.0 I realized that something wrong with my certificates (see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68843038/artemis-2-18-0-replica-set-doesnt-work-properly)). There is no SSL connections between brokers and clients.

Here is how I generated my certificates:

```xml
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout private.key -x509 -days 365 -out brokerRoot.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=Maryland/L=Aberdeen/O=TestCompany/OU=IT/CN=test/emailAddress=test@gmail.com" -passin pass: passphrase

openssl pkcs12 -inkey private.key -in brokerRoot.pem -export -out broker_ks.p12 -password pass:keyStorePassword

keytool -import -alias broker -keystore client_ts.p12  -file brokerRoot.pem -deststoretype pkcs12 -storepass trustStorePassword -noprompt
```

and I'm using same `client_ts.p12` and `broker_ks.p12` on clients and on brokers. So the hostnames should match but it doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ActiveMQ Artemis [upgrade instructions for 2.18.0](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/versions.html#2180) references says:

> ...core clients will now expect the `CN` or Subject Alternative Name values of the broker's SSL certificate to match the hostname in the client's URL.

When you use the `openssl` command to create `private.key` you specify `CN=test`. This means your hostname must be `test` and your client should also use `test` in its URL.

Since it's not working my guess is that your hostname is *not* `test`. Therefore you need to change your SSL cert on the broker to use the proper `CN` value which matches the hostname of the broker and then use that in the client's URL.

Comment: If I generate private1.key, private2.key and private3.key for artemis01,02,03 and I will have for each artemis broker their own ```"broker_ks"``` and ```"client_ts"``` my question is which one should I use then for client's URL ? can  be used any of them ? or should I generate special for clients their own certificates with ```CN``` matching hostname of the client ? I hope my question is clear :)

Comment: As long as the hostname you use in your URL matches what is defined in the certificate then you can use any one you want.